# Como declarar várias condições dentro de um if

Tags: php

Tenho dois `ifs` que levam em conta 3 condições, uma delas com múltiplas possibilidades.

Estou fazendo assim, mas não está dando certo:

```
if (($var1 == $var2) && ($var3 == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 12) && ($var4 > 16)) {
    $var5--;
}

if (($var1 == $var2) && ($var3 == 4 || 6 || 9 || 11) && ($var4 > 15)) {
    $var5--;
}
```

Nos meus testes o script está tirando sempre 2 de `$var5`, quando era para retirar apenas 1, porque `$var3` nunca corresponderá nos dois casos. Então acho que ele não está considerando esta condição. Já pesquisei aqui, e todos os exemplos que encontrei mostram no máximo duas condições.

Qual a forma correta de declarar várias condições dentro de um `if`, sendo que algumas destas condições podem ter múltiplas possibilidades e utilizar outros operadores dentro da condição (`$var3` no exemplo acima). Valeu desde já.

Comment: No teu primeiro `if` faça assim: `if (($var1 == $var2) && ($var3 == 1 || $var3 == 3 || $var3 == 5 || $var3 == 7 || $var3 == 8 || $var3 == 12) && 
   ($var4 > 16)) {`, aplique a mesma lógica no segundo `if`.

Comment: Ah, era isso, valeu! Precisa sempre repetir a variável né...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Como disse o qmechanik](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67763/como-declarar-v%c3%a1rias-condi%c3%a7%c3%b5es-dentro-de-um-if#comment138343_67763), precisaria ser

```
($var3 == 1 || $var3 == 3 || $var3 == 5 || $var3 == 7 || $var3 == 8 || $var3 == 12)
```

Isso porque do jeito que você tinha feito, `1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 12` é entendido como uma única expressão (`$var3 ==  (1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 12)`), que resulta em `1`, que é `true`.

Uma outra maneira de fazer é usar [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array), fica um pouco mais limpo:

```
$opcoesVar3 = array(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 12);
if (($var1 == $var2) && in_array($var3, $opcoesVar3) && ($var4 > 16)) {
    $var5--;
}
```

Comment: Não tinha nem imaginado fazer com array. +1